# Regex which works in JavaScript not working in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm working on a script to remove certain unneeded images on iOS devices; here are some examples of the file names that the regex would be tried against.

```
./Black_0_WifiBars.png
./Black_0_WifiBars@2x.png
./Black_0_WifiBars@3x.png
```

I have a regex which I'm trying to use to match png files which do not end with @2x.png or @3x.png: `.*/\w*(?!@[23]x)\.png`. This works and matches the first example when I have the above examples and the aforementioned regex in a tester site such as http://regexpal.com/. However, when I try to use it in bash, like this:

```
find . -regex ".*/\w*(?\!@[23]x)\.png"
```

It doesn't give any results, even in directories where files that should be matched exist.

Is there an issue with how I have the regex formatted? Is something I'm using in it not supported in bash? (I'm on OS X 10.10.1).

Comment: You should be aware that there are countless variants of regex, and with bash you'll encounter no less than four (BRE, ERE, PCRE and extglob), some of which have subtypes. An expression in one dialect may not work in another, as you've just discovered.

Comment: I tested your original regex and it doesn't work in https://www.regex101.com/#pcre . And I suggest you use this one because at least this one is PCRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your filenames don't contain an @ otherwise, you can use this:

```
find . -regex '.*/[^@]*\.png'
```

Comment: You'll need single-quotes for that to not hit history expansion (in an interactive shell). Which is probably why the OP added it.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I jumped to conclusions. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-not` as a parameter before `-regex` and eliminate the negative lookahead:

```
find . -not -regex ".*@[23]x\.png"
```

Comment: This matches files that don't end in .png.

Comment: Add more to the `find` to get files with the png suffix:  `find . \( -not -regex ".*@[23]x\.png" \) -and -regex ".*\.png$"`